# How can I change drawerActiveBackgroundColor in React Navigation 6?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I change `drawerActiveBackgroundColor` in React Navigation 6 here is my code:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        drawerActiveBackgroundColor: "red",
      }}
      drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        options={{
          drawerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#c6cbef',
            width: 240,
          },
        }}
        name="Login"
        component={Login}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="SignUp"
        component={SignUp}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use

`activeTintColor`: Color for the icon and label when the item is active.

`inactiveTintColor`: Color for the icon and label when the item is inactive.

`activeBackgroundColor`: Background color for item when it's active.

`inactiveBackgroundColor`: Background color for item when it's inactive.

Comment: This doesn't work. Could it be because i'm using a custom drawer?

Answer (score 0):

You will find those options inside Drawer.Screen > options.. something like this:

```
<Drawer.Screen
      options={{
        headerShown: false,
        drawerActiveBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
        drawerActiveTintColor: 'white',
        drawerInactiveTintColor: 'white',
      }}
      name="TabNavigator"
      component={TabNavigator}
    />
```